# Embedding Google Maps without using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe

I am simply trying to embed Google Maps with a dynamically changing address (taken from a database), but I want to remain in http. Every time I try to embed Maps, it loads, but several errors are sent to the console (over 60 iterations of the same error):

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://mydomain.com from frame with URL https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=address&z=14&output=embed. 
The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.
```

How do I fix this? My iframe code:

```
document.getElementById("deMap").src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q='+arr[5]+'&hnear='+arr[5]+'&z=14&output=embed';
```

Relevant HTML:

```
    <div id="deRight">
        <iframe id="deMap" width="405px" height="150px" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)"></iframe><br>Contact Info:<br>
        <div id="deContact"></div><br>
        Additional Info.:<br>
        <div id="deInfo"></div>
        <div class="footer" style="width:410px">
            <hr style="width:100%; height:1px; background-color: #CCC; border:0px; margin: 0px; margin-bottom:5px"/>
            <button class="formBtn" onclick="editEvt()">Edit Event</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I visit the page, it forces HTTPS. I need my website to run without error, but I don't know how to import Google Maps without it forcing https.

Comment: I don't have an SSL certificate so I can't put my site into HTTPS. How can I import Google Maps without getting this error?

Comment: Just because your site doesn't have a cert, doesn't mean you can't access/import stuff that does. Do you get the error when you import via https. Post the HTML.

Comment: If I import jQuery through HTTPS, I don't get an error, but I think this has something to do with google maps trying to send something to the parent (my site which is http) through https.

Comment: The error is coming from this line: `%7Bmain,mod_util,mod_act,mod_act_s,mod_actbr,mod_appiw,mod_mssvt,mod_pphover,mod_rst,mod_strr%7D.js:739`, which is not mine, clearly.

Comment: Apparently this is very common and only happens in Chrome. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43173

Comment: If so, then I think you are fine. YouTube embeds have write javascript errors as well. As long as it doesn't break YOUR code, or the map in question, you should be fine. However, I know you can embed items via https on a non-secure site. If you do it the other way around is when you have issues.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change your `iframe` to a `div`. Then include the following script in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Depending on what you want to do with the addresses in your database and how they are formatted, there are several directions you can go from here. One example is if you had text addresses and wanted to center the map on them. You could do that as follows:

1. Load the Google Maps API and create your Geocoder object.
2. Create your map object and use it to fill your `div`. As in your code, height and width must be set explicitly: `<div id="deMap" style="width: 405px; height: 150px;"></div>`.
3. Query the Geocoder object to get address coordinates.
4. Center the map, etc.

See below:

```
// Step 1
var G = google.maps;
var geocoder = new G.Geocoder();

// Step 2
var deMap = document.getElementById('deMap');
var center = new G.LatLng(0, 0);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: G.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new G.Map(deMap, mapOptions);

// Step 3
function changeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, parseResult);
}

// Step 4
function parseResult(res, status) {
    if (status == G.GeocoderStatus.OK && res.length) {
        var latlng = res[0].geometry.location;
        map.set_center(latlng);
    }
    else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
}
```

For more information, consult Google Maps JavaScript API, which is thoroughly documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

You can also see how I implemented it to accomplish a seemingly similar task [here](http://www.adrianlarson.com/earthquakes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but changing "source=embed" to "output=embed" seems to fix the issue for me. I still get the same JavaScript errors, but the map loads and works perfectly.